# Is there any version of Selenium basic for .NET 4.8?

Tags: .net, windows

My workstation has only .NET framework 4.8 activated, and I have no admin priviledges to active .NET 3.5 in control panel.

Is there any version of Selenium basic for .NET 4.8 on Windows 10?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this, it worked for me. I had exactly your same problem (more recent .NET framework, no rights to change it)

https://gist.github.com/florentbr/6be960752fc852ee99eece6b4acb8ba7

It is a solution written by florentbr that reinstall Selenium by using the currently installed .Net version.

Comment: I've edited/improved the post that was deleted by moderator

Comment: Don't rely on links for your answer. Always put content in a code block (you can still link to the source for credit) as links go dead over time.

Comment: I followed instructions on the link you posted and it works perfectly